# Full Permissions in Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api

We made a software using PHP Laravel that was a more robust search engine for Instagram. When the API got closed off we lost or access. Does anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: Please include the API version, as well as the relevant part of your code that uses it.

Comment: Not sure on the part of code - but right now we are in Sandbox mode but need full access in order for the software to function correctly